# JSON.NET Serialization on an object with a member of type Stream?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net

Hopefully this is an easy fix that I have overlooked. I have an object passed into an event handler that I want to serialize that object using JSON.NET, like so:

```
public void OnEvent(IEventObject foo)
{
    // Serialize foo to string/disk here?
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(foo, Formatting.Indented);
}
```

It appears that one or more of foo's members are streams. I already recognize that Streams are not serializable since they are an abstraction over data and not the data itself. This makes sense.

I do not know how to serialize this object anyway by either:

- a) Converting the streams into data and serializing that
- b) Ignoring the streams and serialize the remaining members

One big caveat to this is that I do not have access to IEventObject or its implementations, so I cannot mark up any of these objects with attribute flags.

The only solution I have come up with is to wrap this object in my own class, mark it up appropriately, and serialize that. Later I would deserialize back into my own class, and convert it into the original object. I don't like this approach since it involves an extra object and conversion step, and would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: I faced quite the same issue and had no choice but to wrap this in an object of mine which is totally serializable. if there's another option I would be pleased to hear it too :-)

Comment: @Bartdude you can check out my answer.

Comment: @TimS. Unfortunately in my case, I ended up having to implement the wrapper object since I do not have local access to concrete types to deserialize back into. Otherwise the accepted answer is a great solution for this problem.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By default, Json.NET will try to serialize the properties of the stream, which isn't very useful. You can modify the behavior by creating your own [contract resolver](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ContractResolver.htm). Here's an example that ignores all `Stream`s entirely:

```
public class IgnoreStreamsResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(
        MemberInfo member,
        MemberSerialization memberSerialization
    )
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (typeof(Stream).IsAssignableFrom(property.PropertyType))
        {
            property.Ignored = true;
        }
        return property;
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var eo = new EventObject { OtherValue = 2, MyStream = new MemoryStream(bytes) };
var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(eo,
  new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new IgnoreStreamsResolver() });
// {"OtherValue":2}
```

By modifying other properties of the [`JsonProperty`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm), you can make other changes. The one that looks like it might be most useful to you is `Converter`, which would let you specify your own class to define how to serialize the `Stream` (e.g. convert it to a `byte[]` and serialize that as base64).

All of this is done without any changes to the interface or implementing class.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'll check back after implementing and testing this myself. Thanks.